# Simplest mutli-fadeing script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for script working like on Dribbble (appearing overlay when you mouse over). 
But it must be multi... I mean used for many images on the site. Simple as much.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a particular Javascript library?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) mouse event you can achieve the behaviour you want.

```
$("img").hover(function() { //select the image which is hovered
    $(this).css("opacity","0.5"); //apply opacity for this image

}, function() {
    $(this).css("opacity","1"); //change to opacity to default
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mVWdQ/

For [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you can use a [class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) which be used only for the required images instead of an [element](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) as `img`.

Another way is to use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

```
$("img").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity:0.5},500);

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({opacity:1},500);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mVWdQ/1/